# Choosing a filepath to export .xlsx file VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a bit of code that allows the user to choose the file path of a folder before exporting data in a separate .xlsx file to that folder. Its easy enough to look up a folder's path beforehand and hard code it in, but I want this program to allow the user to choose a folder each time. As it is, I have this function that utilizes the excel open file dialog box. From there, I am able to find the folder I need, and just copy the file path from the top bar and hit cancel. Here's the code:

```
Function GetFileDestination() As String
    Dim DataObj As New MSForms.DataObject

    'This MsgBox just tells the user what to do
    MsgBox "To get the file Destination, the 'Open File' Dialog Box will open. Go to the folder_
    you want to use, click on the bar at the top, and copy the destination. Then hit Cancel",_
    vbOKOnly, "Finding the File Destination"

    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogOpen).Show
    DataObj.GetFromClipboard
    GetFileDestination = DataObj.GetText
End Function
```

This does the job, but it seems pretty sloppy, since it forces the user to manually copy the file path needed and then cancel the open file dialog box. 
Does anyone know a more creative and clean way about this while still keeping the same functionality?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/294728-browse-folder-visual-basic-applications.html)?

Comment: This works great, Thank You Rusk! No clue how most of it works, but I'm not complaining!

Comment: I have added the answer and its explanation for your reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Function GetFolder(strPath As String) As String
Dim fldr As FileDialog
Dim sItem As String
Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With fldr
    .Title = "Select a Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = strPath
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
NextCode:
GetFolder = sItem
Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

Here's the description:

1. `Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)` - The folder dialog prompts the user to
   select a directory path.
2. `strPath` - Default path which will be passed on to the function.
3. `show` - If the user chooses to cancel the dialog, the value '0' will be assigned, otherwise the value '-1' is assigned.
4. `GetFolder = sItem` - The path of the folder selected/opened is returned by this statement,
   else Null is returned if **Cancel** button is clicked.

Hope this clears the overall logic used.